# LINQ via LinqPad - Trying to link to 2 FKs from one Entity but only displaying one

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linqpad

I have the following 2 table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE Project 
(
   ProjectId INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   ProjectOwnerId INT NOT NULL,
   SupervisorId INT NULL,
   ... other attributes ...
   CONSTRAINT [FK_ProjectOwner FOREIGN KEY (EmployeeId) REFERENCES Employee (EmployeeId),
   CONSTRAINT FK_Supervisor FOREIGN KEY (EmployeeId) REFERENCES Employee (EmployeeId)
)
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE Employee
(
    EmployeeId INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    Name NVARCHAR(20) NULL,
    ... other attributes ...
)
```

When I reverse engineer these tables using Code First and try to query it via LinqPad, I don't see how I can query the 2nd EmployeeId, i.e.

LinqPad:

```
Projects.Include(p => p.Employee)
```

But what I get is the following results:

```
ProjectId | ProjectOwnerId | SupervisorId | Employee
----------  --------------   ------------   --------
100         101              52             Employee (hyperlink)
200         122              52             Employee (hyperlink)
```

When I try to bind the results via my application:

```
Project | ProjectOwner   | Supervisor
-------   --------------   ------------ 
Proj 1    John Smith       John Smith 
Proj 2    Foo Bar          Foo Bar
```

It seems that I am only able to navigate to the Employee (4th column above) which is linked to the ProjectOwnderId and not the SupervisorId, thus I am only seeing the names of the ProjectOwnners. I know that the ProjectOwnderId and SupervisorId are different, so I should be seeing different names.

Comment: Please also show the mappings.